# Correct way to concatenate bitwise operations?

Tags: c++

Im in need to concatenate some bitwise operations but the current output seems to be wrong. The splitted operations are similar to this :

```
unsigned char a = 0x12
unsigned char x = 0x00;
x = a << 4;
x = x >> 4;
```

expected result x = 0x02;
current result x = 0x02;

If i try to concatenate the operations the result is not correct:

```
unsigned char a = 0x12
unsigned char x = 0x00;
x = (a << 4) >> 4;
```

expected result x = 0x02;
current result x = 0x12;

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenation"? What do you expect?

Comment: The result of `a << 4` will be an `int`, so you have to cast it back down before `>> 4`, i.e. `x = static_cast<unsigned char>(a << 4) >> 4;`.

Comment: Is it my imagination, or did you perform an operation, undo that operation, and then expect it to output something different from the original. There are some good attempts at answers here, so I'm probably missing something. Can you (or anyone) explain why you think it'd be something different than `0x12`?

Comment: @Chipster `0x12 << 4` would be `0x120` but it is truncated to `0x20` when stored as an `unsigned char`, so shifting it back only returns `0x02` and not `0x12`. the answers explain why the truncation is happening in case 1 but not in case 2

Comment: @kmdreko Ah, because it's in theory only a char. Got you. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `(a << 4)` is cast to int (via [Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)), so `(0x12 << 4) >> 4` is essentially `0x12`

What you want to do is convert back `(a << 4)` to `unsigned char` by using `static_cast`

The final code:

```
   unsigned char a = 0x12;
   unsigned char x = 0x00;
   x = static_cast<unsigned char>(a << 4) >> 4;
```

Comment: @Chipster the point is : he hope since char is 8 bits, `a << 4 ` give 2 since the 1 is over the 8 bit size. Too bad the operation is made in int, and the one is never erase

Comment: thank you Martin m for your explanation. i will use your solution.

Comment: @Gardener if a compiler would have masked the lower 8-Bits here, even on an 8-Bit machine, it would be in violation of the rules of the C++ language, specifically [\[expr.shift\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1), [\[conv.prom\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#prom-1), and [\[basic.fundamental\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#4)…

Answer (score 2):

**Compiler is NOT applying integral promotions for the >> and << operations**

You might think that

```
x = (a << 4) >> 4;
```

Would use a byte-wide register for the operation, but the compiler promotes the char a to an int before doing the shift, preserving the bits that are shifted to the left.

You can solve this by doing this:

```
x = ((a << 4) & 0xff) >> 4;
```

Again, the issue is that integral promotion preserves the bits until the final cast.

Comment: Please note that the problem here is not that the compiler has failed to do anything. The problem is that the expectations of the person who wrote this code have failed to align with reality. By the rules of the C++ language, operands to the built-in `>>` and `<<` operators are subject to integral promotions. The compiler has done exactly what it always was supposed to do, even on an 8-Bit computer…

Comment: thank you for your explanation,
Yes, i was not aware of the integral promotion.